# Counting indices from numpy where

Tags: python, numpy

So I have two rather large lists (3636586 values in both) and I am trying to use np.where() to find the number of values that satisfy two conditions using those two lists. The lists are

```
cat1 = [  0.01027171   0.01691939   0.01614619 ...,  10.18688393  10.21286678
  10.20675182]
cat2 = [  4.81194684e-09   5.13640614e-08   5.48405854e-09 ...,   2.95787549e-06
3.43822015e-09   2.17239404e-09]
```

I then use np.where():

```
summ = np.array([])

summ = np.append(summ, np.where((cat1 > 6.) & (cat2*1000 > .83)))

print(summ)
>>>[ 3615964.  3616643.  3616732.  3617188.  3618296.  3618976.  3619040.
3619205.  3619429.  3620039.  3620142.  3620185.  3620487.  3620810.
3621045.  3621375.  3621396.  3621828.  3622030.  3622326.  3622713.
3622999.  3623137.  3623202.  3624357.  3624919.  3625077.  3626185.
3626558.  3626666.  3627142.  3627279.  3627660.  3628004.  3628558.
3629997.  3630053.  3630128.  3630801.  3631271.  3631567.  3632210.
3632269.  3632285.  3632589.  3633107.  3633816.  3634833.  3635190.
3635307.  3635608.  3635711.  3635767.  3636159.  3636227.]
```

So I know these are the indices of the values that satisfy the conditions and I can call len(summ) to find the total amount, which is 55. However, my problem is that I want to later use this in a loop (which is why there is the np.append() nonsense in the beginning, I was just premature in putting that in) and finding len(summ) just gives the total number of indices from all loops. Is there anyway I can find the total amount of indices from each loop? If I try finding the length of the np.where() list, I get this:

```
summ = np.array([])
summ = np.append(summ, len(np.where((cat1 > 6.) & (cat2*1000 > .83))))

print(summ)
>>>[ 1.]
```

I want it to output 55. That way, when I put it in a loop, it will output the count of indices that satisfy the conditions instead of just outputting the indices themselves with no separation. I hope it would look something like this:

```
 sample_array = [.39, .29, .12, ...] #array of some length
 summ = np.array([])
for i in sample_array:
  summ = np.append(summ, len(np.where((cat1 > 6.) & (cat2*1000 > i)))) #len() currently doesn't work like how I want it to 

print(summ)
>>> [55, 23, 45, ...] #array of the count of indices for each loop that satisfy the conditions
```

When I run it like this, I get an output of a list of 1's, like it behaved above. I've tried sum(np.where(...)) but that just outputs the indices like in the beginning when I just printed summ.

Comment: You can get those lengths with `np.count_nonzero((cat1 > 6.) & (cat2*1000 > i))` pretty efficiently. Also, to store those lengths, it might be a better idea to initialize `summ` as zeros before going into the loop and at each iteration use an iterator to assign the computed lengths into it by indexing instead of appending.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks so much! This was so frustrating to figure out that I think I just became too hung up on using np.where(). This works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! Seems like you have sorted out your issues from yesterday too.

Comment: @Divakar yes! I kept messing around with a lot of things and my problems kept changing, but I finally nailed something down today.

Comment: `np.where` returns a tuple; `len(np.where(...)[0])` should give the desired number.  `np.where` calls `np.nonzero`, which in turn uses `count_nonzero` to allocate its response arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot get it by using np.where, if you want the length of the indices satisfying your condition, a better approach would be to use boolean conditioning and then use 'np.count_nonzero' over it.

For instance what you could do is:

np.count_nonzero((cat1 > 6.) & (cat2*1000 > .83)) to get the length of the indices satisfying your condition. Hope that helps!